# Youtube API: Get subscribers counts of a million channels

Tags: mysql, youtube, google-api, youtube-api, quota

scenario: MySQL database with a million entries, containing Youtube channel IDs and subscribers counts. Now I would like to update the subscribers counts periodically (maybe once a week).

I am wondering if such large requests are even possible with the API? And if so, what would be the most efficient way to get the subscribers count of a million channels? And if not so, can you think of a work-around?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Socialblade has a large index of channel statistics. I didn't find an official API, but [the socialblade-data npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socialblade-data) might help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to consider doing them in batches you should check the Google developer console see what your quota is for the API currently.   If there is a pencil icon next to the quota you can increase it.

Also checking the [YouTube Data API (v3) - Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) might help you decide how many to run each day.